# Inverse of @DependsOn annotation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Spring (and presumably other DI containers, but I'm using Spring) recognises the @DependsOn annotation. You use this to identify any other beans that must be initiated BEFORE this bean, eg

```
@Component
@DependsOn({"initiatedFirst", "initiatedSecond"})
public class InitiatedThird {

//...
```

Is there an analogous annotation that means that the supplied beans must be initiated AFTER the annotated bean? For example

```
@Component
@DependencyOf({"initiatedSecond", "initiatedThird"})
public class InitiatedFirst {

//...
```

I would have thought this would be quite a common use case for when you don't have access to the source / initialisation of a bean but want to configure some other beans beforehand. Does such an annotation exist?

Answer (score 7):

No, but if you don't have access to code, you still can use xml

```
<bean id="initiatedSecond" class="..." depends-on="initiatedFirst" />
<bean id="initiateThird" class="..." depends-on="initiatedSecond" />
```

and so on...

**Edit**

Other option is to use a  `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to add the dependences via `BeanDefiniton.setDependsOn(String[])`.

For example (Not tested)

```
public class DependencyConfigurer implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private Map<String, String[]> dependencies = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        for (String beanName : dependencies.keySet()) {
            BeanDefinition bd = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
            bd.setDependsOn(dependencies.get(beanName));
        }

    }

    public Map<String, String[]> getDependencies() {
        return dependencies;
    }

    public void setDependencies(Map<String, String[]> dependencies) {
        this.dependencies = dependencies;
    }

}
```

Another option is to make a well know early instantiated bean to depends on your bean. (seems ugly but will work).

Finally you could override `AbstractApplicationContext.onRefresh()` and instantiate your beans.

Comment: The problem with this is that I am hoping to import a spring xml file where the depending bean has been fully configured. What I'm talking about would minimise any repeated config.

Comment: I just added all options that i can see quickly.