# How to add a bean dependency from another module in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-bean

I have two modules: `module1` and `module2`.
`module2` depends on `module1`.

Configuration in the `module1`:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationInModule1 {

    @Bean
    public FirstBean firstBean() {
        return new FirstBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecondBean secondBean(FirstBean firstBean) {
        return new SecondBean(firstBean);
    }
}
```

Configuration in the `module2`:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationInModule2 {

    @Bean
    public SomeBeanForModule2 beanForModule2(FirstBean firstBean) {
        return new SomeBeanForModule2(firstBean);
    }
}
```

As you can see both beans `secondBean` and `beanForModule2` depends on `firstBean`.
I need to make sure that when the project is compiled with `module2` then `beanForModule2` **should be initialized before** `secondBean`. If there is no `module2` then `secondBean` **should be initialized in a standard flow**.

Is it possible to configure it in Spring?

P.S. I need to control the order of been initialization. I know that there is a special annotation `@DependsOn` which can be used to setup indirect dependency, but in my case I cannot use it on `secondBean` because the dependency `beanForModule2` is optional and is placed in another module.

Comment: I only assume those are on different package than SpringBootApplication right?

Comment: You can try to use constructor injection to force order of creation but im not sure if that fits your needs.

Comment: There are 2 spring boot applications which use `module1` but in one application I use `module2` and I need to guarantee that `secondBean` will be initialized after `beanForModule2`. Do you know how to use `constructor injection` to force such order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by using `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. We need to define our custom `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and setup necessary dependencies there. 
Spring won't execute beans initialization before calling `postProcessBeanFactory` method.
To solve the above problem we should define our custom `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` like this one:

```
public class JBCDependencyBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

        BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("secondBean");
        beanDefinition.setDependsOn("beanForModule2");
    }

}
```

After that we should make a **static** bean with our `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. Something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationInModule2 {

    @Bean
    public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor dependencyBeanFactoryPostProcessor() {
        return new JBCDependencyBeanFactoryPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeBeanForModule2 beanForModule2(FirstBean firstBean) {
        return new SomeBeanForModule2(firstBean);
    }
}
```

Spring will search for all beans. Then it will execute `postProcessBeanFactory` in our `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. We will make a dependency from `secondBean` to `beanForModule2` and then spring will call bean initialization by following our dependencies.

P.S. Thanks to @Tarun for sharing the link.

Answer (score 1):

Spring takes care of order of bean initialization, So if one bean depends on other then Spring will first initialize dependency Beans then it will initialize dependent Beans.
In your case `FirstBean` will always initialize prior than `SomeBeanForModule2`  without any additional config.

And if Dependency Bean which is `FirstBean` in your case is not declared(i.e module1 is not there) then Spring will throw `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. So module2 cannot initialized without module1.

**EDIT:-**
For Ordering of Bean Initialization, you can use @DependsOn even if Beans are in seperate File.

Just add `@import(ConfigurationInModule2.class)` in ConfigurationInModule1 class in  your module1.
And use `@DependsOn("beanForModule2")` on secondBean.

This will help:-  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16297827/4720870

Comment: Looks like my question isn't fully clear. I added a `P.S.` section to the question. The question is about `spring bean initialization order setup`.

Comment: @Alexandr Actually you can use @ DependsOn for your requirement

Comment: Maybe there is a way which I am missing but I don't know the way to make `secondBean` depend on `beanForModule2` in the `module2` by using `@DependOn` annotation. As I mentioned in my question. `module2` depends on `module1`. If I mark `secondBean` with `@DependOn` then it means that `module1` depends on `module2` which isn't suitable for me (see the question)

Comment: I have marked the important text in bold in my question, so that it would be more clear. As I've explained in the question, `module1` doesn't depend on `module2`. So, it means that your solution won't work when there is no `module2` the app. It will work only when `module2` is present in the app. As I said, `secondBean` depends on `beanForModule2` **only** when `module2` exists. I.e. only when `beanForModule2` exists.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I used the idea form that answer to solve the problem.

Comment: @Alexandr I fully understand your problem, But edit in post is just for others' references.